# How to retrive a specific object in laravel firebase?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using laravel as a framework and database as a Firebase i want to fetch the data based  on the some key value ,for that i wrote following code

```
<?php

class TestController extends Controller
{
    private $database;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->database = FirebaseService::connect();
    }

    public function get(Request $request){
        $name = $request->name;  //from api request the value is test
        $data = $this->database->getReference('/users/')
                                ->orderByValue('name')
                                ->equalTo($name)->getValue();
        return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
    }
}
```

but it's throwing following error

```
Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Database\UnsupportedQuery: Index not defined, add &quot;.indexOn&quot;: &quot;.value&quot;,
```

can you please help me to fetch the particular value data ..?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to set `indexOn` `users/{uid}/name`, then query with [`equalTo`](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/stable/realtime-database.html#equalto):

```
$snapshot = $this->database
    ->getReference('users')
    ->orderByChild('name')
    ->equalTo($request->name)
    ->getSnapshot();
```

Comment: can you tell me how i have to set `users/{uid}/name` through code

Comment: You can set the index in the console, with security rules - or when deploying `database.json`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to order by value, you must define an index, otherwise the Firebase API will refuse the query.

```
{
    "users": {
        ".indexOn": "name"
    }
}
```

you can set that index in Firebase console -> Database Rules

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data